# Is there an academic template to present a software?

Tags: software-papers

I'd like to know if there is a template, or a standard or a suggested methodology, to outline a paper that speaks about a software.
The arguments I cover are related to the background, the problem it solves, the approach, the architecture, the benchmark and the comparison with other tools.

Comment: I think your question answers itself. You have a decent outline right there. I don't know of a "standard" version, though.

Comment: Have a look at the papers in Journal of Statistical Software and see if that format is useful for your software. Even if it's not right, it might be a good start.

Comment: And if not statistical software, look at papers from several journals that you might submit to, based on papers you have read already during your research. It seems unlikely that you haven't read any similar papers...